# How to add a submenu item to a MenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms

OK so I have a MenuStrip called Form1.menuStrip1. Form1.menuStrip1 has two items horizontally called Menu and Lists. What I want to do is add a new submenu item to the Lists menu. I have a string called mystring, and I want that to be the title of the new Item.

Something like this

```
void AddItem(string mystring) 
{ 
   // add mystring 
}
```

Comment: A good way to be able to do what you can do using the designer, is to look at the code generated in "YourForm.Designer.cs", and do the same.

Answer (score 17):

here is the sample

```
ToolStripMenuItem fileToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
ToolStripMenuItem loadLogsToolStripMenuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
fileToolStripMenuItem1.Name = "File";
loadLogsToolStripMenuItem1.Name ="Logs";

this.fileToolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.loadLogsToolStripMenuItem1
}
```

then you would have File->Logs if you want to add more subItem to File just use add more after this.loadLogsToolStripMenuItem1.

Comment: You can also use Add instead of AddRange.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do what you need

```
void AddItem(string mystring) 
{     
   ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem("Menu");
   item.Text = myString;
   MainMenu.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: It add a whole new mainmenu item, i need it to add to a submenu of an already existing main menu.